# Using java i m trying to replace i for e ;e for a and a for i from user input

Tags: java

Using Java I’m trying to replace i for e ;e for a and a for i from user input. For example, input:

```
The ear is big.
```

output from the program is:

```
Tha air es beg.
```

Both upper case and lower case of aforementioned letters must be encrypted.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test{

    public static void main(String[]  Args);

        System.out.println("Enter String:");
        new Scanner=Scanner kb(System.in);
        String old=kb.nextLine();

        String modified=old.replaceAll("i","e").replaceAll("e","a").replaceAll("a","i").trim();
        System.out.println( "\n The Output is="+modified );
    }
}
```

Comment: the title and structure is unpleasing.....

Comment: how to do using classes and structures

Comment: I am referring to your questions layout and structure..

Comment: It’s like there is no question in your question? Assuming you meant to ask for help fixing a program that doesn’t behave as desired, you should specify precisely how the behaviour differs from the required. “Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include … a specific problem or error… Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.” Quoted from http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to a number of typos and syntax errors, you are replacing the characters you then test for replacement. I think it would be better to eschew a regex here, and use a `Map<Character, Character>` and `StringBuilder` like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Enter String:");
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    String old = kb.nextLine();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Map<Character, Character> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put('i', 'e');
    map.put('e', 'a');
    map.put('a', 'i');

    for (char ch : old.toCharArray()) {
        if (map.containsKey(ch)) {
            sb.append(map.get(ch));
        } else {
            sb.append(ch);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("\n The Output is=" + sb.toString());
}
```

And add the appropriate `import`(s) after `package` at the top.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
```

Comment: how to roll 3 die until it gets same output on all  3